# Forced unwrapping of optional causes crash in Filter

Tags: swift, struct, filter

I am having trouble with this method; I am getting a "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error.

```
let filtererArr = structArrayWithNoOptionals.filter({
    return getFloatNumberFromPriceString(removeCommaFromPriceString($0.totalFare!)) >= minPrice && getFloatNumberFromPriceString(removeCommaFromPriceString($0.totalFare!)) <= maxPrice
})
```

How do I fix this to prevent it from crashing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always try to avoid force unwrapping when possible, in your case you can use `guard let` or `if let` to unwrap it

Change your code this

```
let filtererArr = structArrayWithNoOptionals.filter({
    guard let totalFare = $0.totalFare else { return false }
    return getFloatNumberFromPriceString(removeCommaFromPriceString(totalFare)) >= minPrice &&
        getFloatNumberFromPriceString(removeCommaFromPriceString(totalFare)) <= maxPrice
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Niko said (+1), you should avoid `!` forced unwrapping. Perform optional binding via `if let` or `guard let` instead.

Personally, rather than using `removeCommaFromPriceString` and `getFloatNumberFromPriceString`, I'd probably use a `NSNumberFormatter`.

For example, in Swift 3:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal

let filtererArr = structArrayWithNoOptionals.filter {
    guard let string = $0.totalFare, let totalFareValue = formatter.number(from: string)?.doubleValue else { return false }
    return totalFareValue >= minPrice && totalFareValue <= maxPrice
}
```

The number formatter will automatically handle strings with thousands separators (which I assume is your intent of removing the commas), but it will also handle international number formats (e.g. in Germany, the thousands separator is `.` and the decimal point is `,`).

Comment: Thanks a lot, SIR. Indeed helpful

Comment: You are a wonderful programmer. I could've up- voted you many times if allowed. Thanks